# Is it possible to create a 2D array of VlcPlayerController Controller?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, 2d

```
List<List<VlcPlayerController>> twoDList = List.generate(3, (i) => List.filled(3, '', growable: false), growable: false);
```

Is it possible to create a 2D array of VlcPlayerController?

I've tried

The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'VlcPlayerController'. i get this error message.